# Simple Qt Video streaming application and only sound, no video (white screen)

Tags: android, c++, qt, video, streaming

After an intense search on this site I found nothing which fits
my problem. I want to write a small video streaming client on
an Android 5.1 device. The following code is used:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QWidget *widget=new QWidget;
widget->resize(320,200);

QMediaPlayer *player=new QMediaPlayer;
QVideoWidget *vw= new QVideoWidget;
QHBoxLayout *layout=new QHBoxLayout;

layout->addWidget(vw);
widget->setLayout(layout);
player->setVideoOutput(vw);
player->setMedia(QUrl("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"));
player->play();
widget->show();
```

The problem is, the sound works but I only get a white screen.
the sound is playing but no video.

The VLC player on the android device is playing the video
correctly. I also used a small player in android studio and
it plays the video (but with high latency, so it is not useful for me)

I ran out of options what I can change to make it run.

Comment: It looks like the Qt libraries on your Android device don't have the right codec (H.264)

Comment: Hello, wjhere can i check in the qt kit for the android platform which codec it supports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is not media friendly, if you want to play specific format/codec like MOV or h.264/h.265 ect... in a crossplatform way I advise you to use external lib like QtAV (http://www.qtav.org/) or VLC Qt wrapper (https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlcDemo)

Comment: Thank you, i currently have a look at qmlvlcdemo but the compiler is missing vlc.h (current status). I am currently investigating which package i have to use...

Comment: Did you download it as zip file ? Because github don't fill the zip with git submodule, you need to clone the repository

Comment: No, i used the zip file. Now i cloned the repository and after qmake and build the include QmlVlc is missing. I also cloned the QmlVlc repository and added the path to the .pro file of the demo. Then I get the vlc.h missing error.

Comment: How did you clone the repository ? Because if you did it with command line, you need to init and update your git sub module with "git submodule init" and "git submodule update", https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thank you for the hint regarding the init procedure. I used Tortoise-Git but forgot to init and update the submodules. Now it works and i have to check if there is a possibility to reduce the buffer to decrease the latency. Again, thank you very much...

Comment: It's nothing, we all have a bad time with playing media at the beginning

Comment: One question, you mentioned the QtAV library. I made an Applikation, cloned QtAV with compilation, sdk_install etc. But after deploy, i will recive the message that the 1.12 is not installed. I thought it should come with the apk-package, should it?

Comment: Did you follow wang github wiki ? https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/wiki/Make-app-for-Android I never had this message

Comment: Hello, thank you for your hint with the wiki page. I chose as QtAV version 1.12 because it is the last version. Then i tried the 1.6 import command and now it works, the video is not displayed but this i will work out i think. The reason why it should be 1.6 is not clear for me because I built and installed the 1.12 Version. Anyway i will now try to display the video stream and have a look at the latencies...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that Android devices [do not support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) the QuickTime Format (`MOV`) by default.

VLC Media Player on the other side, [is well-known](https://www.easefab.com/topic-mov/play-mov-files-on-android.html) to be able to correctly play `MOV` videos.

Try testing videos with another format such as `MP4`or `WebM` to see how the program behaves.

---

I once developed a desktop software for streaming audio/video in `Qt` and I had the pleasure to work with the [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) framework.

Among many functionalities, it allows you to convert `MOV` videos to other formats.

You may check the [GStreamer for Android](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/video.html) tutorials and [QtGstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/), a set of well-implemented `GSstreamer` bindings for `Qt`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your hint to gstreamer.I also came across the gstreamer framework and will give it a try. At first i need the libary to be used for cross platform development. I downloaded the installer for x86 and x86_64 (bin and dev) and will investigate them. I will report...

Comment: You should first verifiy that other formats are played in your app @Harold